# How to calculate total score with inputs from user?

Tags: c++

Each applicant is given a score using the data type float. There are two ways for applicants to earn points, applicants will receive 10 points per spell that they have casted and 2 points per wand they own. The applicant’s final score will be calculated by the following formula: total_points + (total_points * donation_percentage). Where the calculation of  donation_percentage will be later explained.  x

This is what I got so far. It seems to compile, but dosent show to accurate result.

```
/*-------------------------------------input-----------------------*/

//input how many different spells the applicant has casted successfully
cout << "How many spells has the applicant succesfully casted?" << endl;
int spellsCasted;
cin >> spellsCasted;

//input how many wands the applicant owns
cout << "How many wands does the applicant own?" << endl;
int wandsOwned;
cin >> wandsOwned;

/*----------------------------------------execute---------------------------*/

//determine the applicant's overall fit score
float total_points = 1;

int spellsPoints, wandsPoints;
spellsPoints: 10 * spellsCasted;
wandsPoints = 2 * wandsOwned;
total_points = spellsPoints + wandsPoints;

cout << "The applicant's total score is: " << total_points << endl;
```

Comment: What input did you provide?  What output did you get?  What output did you expect?

Comment: Please, [turn on your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/f4exzT7ro)!

Comment: Being pedantic:  your declaration should be "`float total_points = 1.0f;`".

Answer (score 1):

You're using a colon instead of an equals sign.

This:

```
spellsPoints: 10 * spellsCasted;
```

should be:

```
spellsPoints = 10 * spellsCasted;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to pay better attention

Comment: @jieya no - you just need to **enable compiler warnings**, and you'll be told of these mistakes